# React - get "invalid hook call" when write (arrow) function component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

got "invalid hook call" when writing function component with arrow function.

I tried to use hooks in functional component just like below.

```
// this will get error

const Foo = () => {
    const fooRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log(fooRef.current);
    }, [])

    return (
      <h1>this is foo</h1>
    );
}

export default Foo;
```

but got error message like below.

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

I have been check 1~3, but still got error.

And I am confused with why code below does not get error message "invalid hook call".

```
// this works well.


const Foo = () => {
    const fooRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log(fooRef.current);
    }, [])
 
    return (
      <h1>this is foo</h1>
    );
}

const Bar = () => <Foo/>

export default Bar;
```

If someone have ideas with these 2 question, please tell me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like whatever's importing this file is not calling it as a React component. You should change that other file so that it does.

For example, if the other file does:

```
import Foo from '/.Foo.js';

// some code that eventually results in...

Foo();
```

replace that call of the import with JSX that calls the import as a component:

```
<Foo />
```

so that it's properly wrapped within `React.createElement`. (If a hook isn't called stemming from a `React.createElement` somehow, React will reject it and throw an error.)

By doing

```
const Bar = () => <Foo/>

export default Bar;
```

This happens to fix the problem because now you're calling Foo as a React component *from inside the file* - but it'd be nicer to fix the importer of the file so that it properly calls it as a component.